# How to Convert Array to string

Tags: c#

I want to convert Array into string as

```
string[] parts={"1","2","3","4"};
```

and output as

```
string str="%1%2%3%4%";
```

Comment: `string.Join("%", parts)` then add in the start and end `%`.

Comment: I think you may have googled this as well.

Comment: Linq: parts.Aggregate("%", (current, next) => current + next + "%")

Comment: @Klaudiuszbryjamus While clever this suffers from the [concatenating strings in a loop problem.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182272(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @juharr But this is simple linq query not in loop so you can use linq

Comment: @Klaudiuszbryjamus While not technically a loop.  The Linq query will still iterate over each element and do string concatenation.

Comment: @juharr I think you are right. I don't look to Aggregate method code.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var str = string.Join("%", parts);
```

And add in the surrounding `%` marks:

```
str = string.format("%{0}%", str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using C#-6 [*string interpolation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx):

```
var str = $"%{string.Join("%", parts)}%";
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning this will only work in C#6.

Answer (score 1):

`string.Join` will concatenate the `string`s in the array with a delimiter.  Then you just have to add the "%" to the beginning and end.

```
string str = "%" + string.Join("%", parts) + "%";
```

Comment: :- thanks its working Properly

Answer (score 0):

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();    
    foreach(string tmp in parts)
    {
       builder.append("%");
       builder.append(tmp);
    }
    builder.append("%");
    string result = builder.ToString();
```